# CSS: Align Menu to Center

Tags: css, alignment, center

I am trying to align the menu to center. I have tried putting in text-align: center !important; in various spots but it didn't do anything.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
.menu_wrapper
width: 88%;
margin: 0 auto;



#main_menu nav ul
position: relative;
padding-left: 2%;
border-top: 1px solid #fff;
border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;

#main_menu nav ul:after
content: "\0020"; 
display: block; 
height: 0; 
clear: both; 
visibility: hidden;

#main_menu nav ul#nav_menu li
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
float: left;
margin-right: 19px;


#main_menu nav ul#nav_menu li a
display: block;
padding: 20px 10px 15px;
font: 11px/1.27em "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
letter-spacing: 0.25em;
color: #fff;
z-index: 2;

#main_menu nav ul#nav_menu li.blob
border-bottom: 1px solid #F00;
bottom: -1px;
height: 1px;
padding-bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
```

Comment: Post your HTML. As a assumption by seeing css code, give `display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto;` to `#main_menu nav ul` class style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to centerize your navigation is to put a display: "table" to your main container. This way you will be sure that everything will be centerized.

```
.menu_wrapper {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**change this section**

```
.menu_wrapper
{
width: 88%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**After change**

```
.menu_wrapper
{
width: 88%;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width:88%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to your CSS:

```
#main_menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or (if you have a top- or bottom-margin to preserve):

```
#main_menu {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

The first example is shorthand for setting vertical margins to zero and horizontal (`left` and `right`) margins to automatic. The vertical doesn't matter so much, but the `auto` setting for your horizontal margins will push the element equally away from the left and right sides of its containing element (or your document, depending on your HTML), thereby centering it.

Note that this horizontal-centering method works only with non-floated, block-displayed, statically or relatively positioned elements—which I'm guessing is fine for your app, but we can't know without seeing your HTML.

Answer (score -1):

In html, 
try this

`<center><div class='menu_wrapper'> your content </div></center>`

Comment: `center` HTML tag is deprecated.